# How to generate html testing reports using jmeter?

Tags: ant, jmeter

i am getting this error message while generating HTML reports using jmeter.
Can you please help me out.

```
Buildfile: D:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\build.xml:88: taskdef doesn't support the "r
```

ef" attribute

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: For creating HTML report & charts through Ant for JMeter test, please check this site : http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround could be to move taskdef file out of target.

Visit the link for further details:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3205

Between, you could try the the loadosophia jmeter plugin for Jmeter reporting. It generates way better reports that are automatically uploaded loadosophia account.

Comment: Now what should i do @TestingWithArif
I want to go with ant only

Answer (score 0):

Here are few suggestions:

1. Double check your `build.xml` file. Line 88 of mine is blank

   [image: Ant Build XML]

   so my expectation is that your build.xml file is corrupt. [Download](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) fresh copy of JMeter and take it from there.
2. You don't need to run JMeter test via Ant in order to generate HTML report. You can switch JMeter's results output to format, compatible with XSLT transformers which generate HTML by adding next few lines to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation, see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
   jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
   ```

   and if you [run JMeter in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   D:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin jmeter.bat -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l D:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\Test.jtl
   ```

   wait for test completion and run `ant report` from the "extras" folder, resulting Test.html file will contain the results you're looking for.
3. Play with different Ant and Java versions. For instance I have:

   - Ant 1.9.6
   - Java 1.8.0_65

   and everything works fine. You can check yours using `ant -version` and `java -version` commands correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [SmartMeter](https://www.smartmeter.io/), which is based on JMeter and also available for free. It can do HTML reports out of the box, even from JMeter results. No extra configuration required, read more this [article](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/smartmeter-load-test-report).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following and check out this detailed documentation: http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/

```
<taskdef name="jmeter" classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"/>
```

Post your `build.xml` if you're still facing any errors.